# ItemLoader causes start_requests()) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: scrapy, items

For some reasons, when the ItemLoader is involved in the code it causes this error

```py
start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Below is the code for `GetTikTokMetricsSpider.py` and `items.py` respectively. The median values work without the ItemLoader process that comes after `GetTikTokMetricsSpider.py` however not getting through to `def get_medians` with the ItemLoader. I tried putting the whole process including the ItemLoader in `start_requests` and it returns the same error. How would the ItemLoader be causing the error here? Here is the code.

**GetTikTokMetricsSpider.py:**

```py
import scrapy
import json
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
import numexpr as ne
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ScrapeTikTok.items import MedsItem
from TikTokLocalPaths import get_project_path


class GettiktokmetricsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'GetTikTokMetricsSpider'
    custom_settings = {
        "FEEDS": {
            "data/metrics.csv": {
                "format": "csv",
                "overwrite": True
            }
        },
        "FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS": [
            "user", "view_med", "like_med", "comment_med", "share_med"
        ],
    }


    def start_requests(self):
        print("START REQUEST")
        users = self.get_users()
        print(users)
        for user in users:
            get_medians = self.get_medians(user)

    def get_medians(self, user):
        print("GET MEDIANS")
        df_counts = self.get_df_counts()
        df_counts.query(f"user == '{user}'", inplace=True)

        df_counts["view_med"] = df_counts["view_count"].median(axis=0)
        df_counts["like_med"] = df_counts["like_count"].median(axis=0)
        df_counts["comment_med"] = df_counts["comment_count"].median(axis=0)
        df_counts["share_med"] = df_counts["share_count"].median(axis=0)

        view_med = df_counts["view_med"].iloc[0]
        like_med = df_counts["like_med"].iloc[0]
        comment_med = df_counts["comment_med"].iloc[0]
        share_med = df_counts["share_med"].iloc[0]

        print(user)
        print(view_med)
        print(like_med)
        print(comment_med)
        print(share_med)

        print(type(view_med))
        print(type(like_med))
        print(type(comment_med))
        print(type(share_med)) #Works til here without below il

        il = ItemLoader(item=MedsItem())
        il.add_value("user", user)
        il.add_value("view_med", view_med)
        il.add_value("like_med", like_med)
        il.add_value("comment_med", comment_med)
        il.add_value("share_med", share_med)
        yield il.load_item()
        print(MedsItem())

    def get_users(self):
        counts_url = self.get_csv_counts_url()
        df_counts = pd.read_csv(counts_url)
        users = df_counts["user"].unique()
        return users

    def get_df_counts(self):
        counts_url = self.get_csv_counts_url()
        df_counts = pd.read_csv(counts_url)
        return df_counts

    def get_csv_counts_url(self):
        url = f"{get_project_path()}/data/counts.csv"
        return url
```

**items.py:**

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from itemloaders.processors import Join, MapCompose, TakeFirst, Identity
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

def get_count(view):
    view_count = str(view)
    if ("Share" or "share"
        or "Comment" or "comment"
        or "Like" or "like") in view_count:
        view_count = "0"
        return view_count
    if "." in view:
        view_count = view_count.replace(".", "")
    if "K" == view[-1]:
        view_count = view_count.replace("K", "000")
    if "M" == view[-1]:
        view_count = view_count.replace("M", "000000")
    return view_count

def get_med(value):
    if type(value) != str:
        str_value = str(value)
    else:
        return value
    return str_value

class CountsItem(scrapy.Item):
    user = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags), output_processor = TakeFirst())
    view_count = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, get_count), output_processor = TakeFirst())
    like_count = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, get_count), output_processor = TakeFirst())
    comment_count = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, get_count), output_processor = TakeFirst())
    share_count = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, get_count), output_processor = TakeFirst())

class MedsItem(scrapy.Item):
    user = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(get_med), output_processor = TakeFirst())
    view_med = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(get_med), output_processor = TakeFirst())
    like_med = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(get_med), output_processor = TakeFirst())
    comment_med = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(get_med), output_processor = TakeFirst())
    share_med = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(get_med), output_processor = TakeFirst())
```

UPDATE SOLVED
It seems the error is caused by the general structure of `scrapy` requiring to yield its `Request` in `start_requests`. A simple solution would be to use a random url or file, and then call `callback=parse`. Here I created an empty html file to minimize the data being passed around, but there's no promise `scrapy` will not change in the future to refuse and automatically terminate once an empty response is detected, in that case I think adding a couple of texts to the file would be fine, but this seems to solve the problem for now :

```
import scrapy
import os
import pandas as pd
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ScrapeTikTok.items import MedsItem
from TikTokLocalPaths import get_project_path, get_project_file_path


class GettiktokmetricsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'GetTikTokMetricsSpider'
    custom_settings = {
        "FEEDS": {
            "data/metrics.csv": {
                "format": "csv",
                "overwrite": True
            }
        },
        "FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS": [
            "user", "view_med", "like_med", "comment_med", "share_med"
        ],
    }


    def start_requests(self):
        create_empty_html = self.create_empty_html()
        empty_html = f"{get_project_file_path()}/data/empty_html.html"
        yield scrapy.Request(empty_html, callback=self.parse)

    def create_empty_html(self):
        empty_html = f"{get_project_path}/data/empty_html.html"
        if os.path.isfile(empty_html) == True:
            pass
        else:
            file = open(f"data/empty_html.html", "w", encoding="utf-8")
            file.write("")
            file.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        users = self.get_users()
        for user in users:
            df_counts = self.get_df_counts()
            df_counts.query(f"user == '{user}'", inplace=True)

            df_counts["view_med"] = df_counts["view_count"].median(axis=0)
            df_counts["like_med"] = df_counts["like_count"].median(axis=0)
            df_counts["comment_med"] = df_counts["comment_count"].median(axis=0)
            df_counts["share_med"] = df_counts["share_count"].median(axis=0)

            view_med = df_counts["view_med"].iloc[0]
            like_med = df_counts["like_med"].iloc[0]
            comment_med = df_counts["comment_med"].iloc[0]
            share_med = df_counts["share_med"].iloc[0]

            il = ItemLoader(item=MedsItem())
            il.add_value("user", user)
            il.add_value("view_med", view_med)
            il.add_value("like_med", like_med)
            il.add_value("comment_med", comment_med)
            il.add_value("share_med", share_med)
            yield il.load_item()

    def get_users(self):
        counts_url = self.get_csv_counts_url()
        df_counts = pd.read_csv(counts_url)
        users = df_counts["user"].unique()
        return users

    def get_df_counts(self):
        counts_url = self.get_csv_counts_url()
        df_counts = pd.read_csv(counts_url)
        return df_counts

    def get_csv_counts_url(self):
        url = f"{get_project_path()}/data/counts.csv"
        return url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `start_requests` doesn't return or yield at all. So the return value is always going to be `NoneType`.

In this line  you hand the process over to the `get_medians` method:

```py
for user in users:
    get_medians = self.get_medians(user)
```

And then in the `get_medians` method you yield the loaded item:

```py
yield il.load_item()
print(MedsItem())
```

So the item is yielded back to the `start_requests` method and stored in the variable `get_medians`.

At this point you should yield the `get_medians` variable that represents the item. Instead the next iteration of the loop begins and the `get_medians` variable is overwritten with the next item.

Simply adding a `yield` statement to your start requests should solve your problem.

For example:

```py
for user in users:
    get_medians = self.get_medians(user)
    yield get_medians
```

Unfortunately even this will likely lead to errors since scrapy takes the output of `start_requests` which is expected to be a `scrapy.Request` object and immediately sends them to the scheduler, and eventually converted into `scrapy.Response` objects.

Since scrapy expects a request object from start_requests and it expects items to be yielded from the `parse` methods you can use just about any request you can think of to get to the parse method and then from there you can execute your code in the parse method.

for example:

```py
    def start_requests(self):
        # you can use any url that will successfully create a response
        # object. this one should work though
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://quotes.toscrape.com")

    def parse(self, response):
        print("START REQUEST")
        users = self.get_users()
        print(users)
        for user in users:
            get_medians = self.get_medians(user)
            yield get_medians

    ...
    ...
```

Comment: I added the line `yield get medians` and it now does print out all data from `def get medians` but there's still no saved metrics.csv and after all yielded data comes the error `if not request.dont_filter and self.df.request_seen(request):
builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dont_filter'`

Comment: That is because you are yielding an item from the `start_requests` method when it expects request objects to be yielded from the start requests method.   Does your spider ever make any requests?

Comment: No that's the problem I just want to run a repeated function from `start_requests` that later yields to items and hence feeds exports.

Comment: @Andrea see the updates to my answer

Comment: It's working now thanks very much. I think I get the general idea of `start_requests` expecting to use `scrapy.Request` requiring an url so instead of hitting random websites I added to the alternative of creating an empty html local file and called that and it worked as well to minimize the amount of not used data being passed around. I will update my answer to that too. Much thanks for the help!

Comment: @andrea Excellent idea.  That was my first thought as well however since it required a few additional steps I figured it was better to make it as simple as possible.